# Using a local variable in an overloaded operator in c++

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue, unordered-map

I'm trying to use the standard library priority queue to order objects of a custom class `Foo`. However comparing the elements depends on a value that they map to in an unordered_map `map`.

I'm trying to construct something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<Foo,double> map;
struct Compare {
   bool operator()(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
      return map[a]<map[b];
   }
}
std::priority_queue<Foo,std::vector<Foo>,Compare> queue;
```

However it looks like I'm not allowed to reference a local variable of an enclosing function.

What is the standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store a reference to `map` as a member variable of `Compare`.

You can get rid of some boilerplate by using a lambda instead of a named function object:

```
auto compare = [&map](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return map[a]<map[b];
};
std::priority_queue<Foo,std::vector<Foo>,decltype(compare)> queue(compare);
```